# Obtain version of Chilkat

Tags: chilkat

In order to obtain the current version of the Chilkat library I'm using, I need to use the `CkGlobal` object.

Do I need to use the `UnlockComponent` method first in order to use this?

Answer (score 1):

Most Chilkat classes have a Version property, including CkGlobal:  https://chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/vcCkGlobalRef.html#prop23

You can always access properties before the lib is unlocked.  This is because in many development environments, the property values may be shown at design time.

In any case, you should unlock once at the start of your program by calling UnlockBundle.  (The individual UnlockComponent methods that exist in older Chilkat classes are deprecated and don't need to be called if CkGlobal.UnlockBundle is called once.)   See the links to "Unlocking Chillkat" at https://www.chilkatsoft.com/readme.asp